# MS Access 2013 Query Criteria

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to put this criteria into MS Access and there is an invalid procedure call.

```
Between Dateadd(mm,-12, now()) and Dateadd(mm,-9,now())
```

I have also tried

```
>= Dateadd(mm, -12,Now()) and <= Dateadd(mm,-9,now())
```

Same error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.

Your date interval code needs to be quoted, otherwise Access will think it's a column name or query parameter.

mm isn't a valid date interval. If you mean month, the interval code is m.

```
BETWEEN DATEADD('m', -12, NOW()) AND DATEADD('m', -9, NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks- too used to working in TSQL stepping back into Access giving some hassels.